# Is radiant floor heating healthy for my small dog?

Tags: dogs, health

I'm thinking about installing **radiant floor** in my home but I'm worried about my dog, a 8kg/18lb Lhasa Apso with the head at 30cm/12" from the floor and a lot of hair.

With a radiant heating system, the floor surface is at 28ºC/82ºF while the lower layers of air, where my dog would be living, are between 22ºC/72ºF and 25ºC/77ºF.

This is not a different temperature to the one we can find in summer (In Spain) but I'm still worried about my dog's health, considering the type of dog he is: Small and hairy.

**Can someone provide me any advice?**

Thank you very much

Comment: Most pets need somewhere cool to retreat to if they get too warm. This certainly applies to cats and dogs (in fact all mammals). Even reptiles need somewhere cool, as well as somewhere warm, so that they can maintain a comfortable body temperature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Mick said, your dog will need somewhere to retreat when he gets too warm. Dogs can't sweat, which is why they pant. Wherever the radiant floor is installed, make certain your dog has a place off the floor if he gets too warm. Any elevated area should be adequate.